# Can't get a response value from Power Automate

Tags: powerapps, power-automate

I have a flow that executed in Power Apps and the result of Power Automate will store to collection, but after executing the flow, the collection still empty of rows.

Here is my code in Power Apps

```
ClearCollect(
    collTest,
    SORExcuteQueryString.Run(varStrQuery)
);
```

And this is my Flow

[All action in Flow are successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6sbE.png)

[Result of Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0xJK.png)

[Result of Flow 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwGoH.png)

[collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhvHR.png)

[apps code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjjSm.png)

[Execute a SQL Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOuYc.png)

[Execute Stored Procedure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q779I.png)

and this is my Scheme of the response

```
    {
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "Area": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "DADays": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "CustomerName": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "SalesmanName": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "ProductName": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "QTY": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "UOM": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "OpportunityNo": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "ProductFamily": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "required": [
            "Area",
            "DADays",
            "CustomerName",
            "SalesmanName",
            "ProductName",
            "QTY",
            "UOM",
            "OpportunityNo",
            "ProductFamily"
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Power Automate (Flow) will show the Run History of each flow execution. Look at the history and determine:

1. If it was Successful
2. Expand each Action in Flow to look at the Inputs/Outputs and Query Strings

   2a. Are there any errors?

   2b. Is there any data in the response from SQL?
3. If the Flow actions are successful, are there any errors in PowerApps where you instantiate the ClearCollect?

   3a. If so, correct the parameters you are passing Flow
4. Click `View/Collections` and see if the Collection is nested JSON

   4a. If so, you have two options for accessing the data

   i. Use `.` (dot notation) to dig into the json **when you create** the collection.

   ii. Use `.` (dot notation) to dig into the json **when you display** the collection in a gallery

**Example1:**

```
ClearCollect(colTest,
    SORExecuteQueryString.Run(varStrQuery)
).items.properties
```

**Example2: Set the gallery `Items` property to something like**

```
colTest.items.properties
```

5. As a last ditch effort, you can `File/Save/Close` PowerApps and reopen the app.

   5a. Sometimes this prompts an "Allow" popup that is required to get a response from a connector (usually only applies to Custom Connectors)
6. Finally, if you're unable to find the problem using above, `View/DataSources`, select the Flow, remove it and re-add it to the PowerApp.

   6a. Usually only need this if you've changed your Flow "Ask in PowerApps" parameters.

   6b. Be careful here! When you choose a Button `OnSelect` (typically) to re-add the Flow, PowerApps will overwrite any code you have written there. Best to copy and paste the code from the OnSelect property then re-add the Flow to the button to avoid this.
7. You might also check `File/Settings/Advanced Settings` for any SQL-related Preview/Experimental settings. Toggle these on/off during troubleshooting to see if that makes a diff.

Comment: Dear @seadude,

thanks for your response, in my MS Flow, there is no error raised up. the flow successfully runned.

I have attached the results of MS Flow

Comment: Ok. Is there an error in PowerApps where you are calling ClearCollect? Your collection is likely nested JSON. Add a screenshot of your Collection (View/Collections).

Comment: yes, the result of flow.. nested JSON.

ok, The screenshot is in the attachment

Comment: See my edited answer. Just add a `.` at the collection or at the gallery to "dig" into the nested json response.

Comment: i am sorry, still not working. the problem is value of response (Ms Flow Action) cannot stored into collection in powerapps.

are u have any solution?

Comment: Is that successful Flow run in "Results of Flow2" screenshot the call from powerapps or from YOUR TESTING in Flow?

Comment: All action in my Flow are successfully executed without error. see attachment (ALL action in Flow are successfully) .

Comment: I'm tapped! Other than the recommendations above, I can't think of any other variables that would affect the Collection from Flow.

Comment: i am sorry @seaDude,

i already figured out the solution, i use the SP for the query String. 
for the parameters of SP, send from powerapps. 

thanks for your response.

but i already found something about the response in MS Flow.

if we use action "Execute a sql query (V2)", the body at the Response / Request have no "Resultset.Table1" .. see attachment "Execute a Sql Query (v2)"

if we use action "Execute Stored Procedure (V2)", the body at the Response / Request hace "ResultSet.Table1".. see attachment "Execute Stored Procedure (v2)"